# Get the hex of 2's complement for negative numbers

Tags: python, twos-complement

I am trying to convert an integer number into an array of byte strings.

```
def int2Hex():
    hex = '%08x' % 32
    bytes = []

    for i in range(0,4):
        bytes.append('0x' + hex[i*2: i*2 + 2])

    return bytes[::-1] #return in little endian
```

The above code works for positive numbers: `['0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x20']`

but when I use a negative number I'll get something like this: `['0x-0', '0x00', '0x00', '0x20']`

What I want for negative numbers is the 2's complement bytes. I am using python 2.

Comment: What internal format are the "bytes" supposed to correspond to - some specific one or the system's native? Not in all platforms `int`s are 32-bit and big-endian. What about numbers that are out of range?

Comment: The task boils down to converting a signed integer to unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make sure the number that is converted is always positive, and then mask the bottom 32 bits, your method can work.

**Code:**

```
OFFSET = 1 << 32
MASK = OFFSET - 1

def int2Hex(num):
    hex = '%08x' % (num + OFFSET & MASK)
    bytes = []

    for i in range(0, 4):
        bytes.append('0x' + hex[i * 2: i * 2 + 2])

    return bytes[::-1]  # return in little endian

print(int2Hex(20))
print(int2Hex(-20))
```

**Results:**

```
['0x14', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00']
['0xec', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
def int2hex(number, bits):
    """ Return the 2'complement hexadecimal representation of a number """

    if number < 0:
        return hex((1 << bits) + number)
    else:
        return hex(number)
```

I hope you find it useful!

Comment: It should also have `assert number>>bits==0` - for numbers larger than the intended number of bits, the algorithm would return garbage.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should return `['0x'+h[i:i+1] for i in range(0,len(h),2)]` where `h=("%%0%d"%(bits//4))%hex(...)` to conform to the problem statement. But that's an unrelated concern, so I don't mind it as it is.